# Fetch multiple rows from one table and Store to another table in php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch multiple row data from one table and on users selection, store only the chosen row into another table.

The problem with this code is that data from table 'FLIGHTS' is fetching accurately from database but when I am trying to store it into another table 'bookFlight' it is storing only NULL values for all columns. Want help!

```
<?php

$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)  
            or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("dbtest",$dbhandle)
            or die("Could not select dbtest");

session_start();

         ////// STORING DATA INTO TABLE 'bookFlight' ////////

 if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
         $company_name   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company_name']);
         $flight_category= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['flight_category']);
         $rates           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rates']);
         $qry    = "INSERT INTO bookFlight"."(company_name,flight_category,rates)". 
                  "VALUES('$company_name','$flight_category','$rates')"; 

    $retval = mysql_query( $qry, $dbhandle );
    if(! $retval ) {
           die('<br><br> Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
      else  {  echo "Entered data successfully\n";   }               
}
              ////// FETCHING DATA FROM TABLE 'flights' ////////

$sql = "SELECT * FROM flights where type_id = 
                                      (SELECT type_id FROM tour WHERE city = 
                                     '{$_SESSION['destination_Address']}')";

$myData = mysql_query($sql,$dbhandle);
$num = mysql_num_rows($myData);

  echo "<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <th> COMPANY NAME :  </th>
  <th> FLIGHT CATEGORY : </th>
  <th> RATES :  </th>
  </tr>";

 for ($i=0; $i <$num; $i++)
{
$record = mysql_fetch_array($myData,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
echo "<form method=post>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $company_name[]= $record['company_name']      ."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $flight_category[]= $record['flight_category']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rates[]= $record['rates']                    ." </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='SELECT'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";  
}
echo"</table>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Comment: You need to pass/post values through form.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Defining your query outside of the function call is also a habit you need to break. It's all too easy to pass in the wrong string as an argument, especially if you're juggling things like `$sql1`, `$sql2` and so on. Supplying the query string directly to the function completely eliminates any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not sending anything except `submit` with your form, and that's why `$_POST` array has nothing except `submit` value.

You need to pass the *row id*(I'm assuming *id* column in this case) along with the form data so that you could insert *that* particular row in `bookFlight` table.

```
for ($i=0; $i <$num; $i++){
    $record = mysql_fetch_array($myData,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
    echo "<form action='?id=".$record['id']."' method='post'>";
    ...
}
```

And once the user hits the *submit* button, this is how you can `INSERT` the data.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $qry = "INSERT INTO bookFlight (company_name, flight_category, rates) SELECT company_name, flight_category, rates FROM flights WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $qry, $dbhandle );
    if(! $retval ) {
        die('<br><br> Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }else {  
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";   
    }               
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: alright thanks it is working.. but now the error arising is that it is storing for only WHERE id= 1 and not for other ids . what do i do now ?

Comment: @Sabah Can you please elaborate what do you mean by *it is storing for only WHERE id= 1 and not for other ids*? Also, you have to move this closing statement `echo "</form>";` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @Sabah Welcome, glad I could help! :-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)